# Getting a P value from the comparison of observed and expected probabilities

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, bootstrap

I'm trying to get my head around how to get P values for a particular problem involving the probability of occurrence of an event, against the random expectation.

Let's say that I observe the occurrence of an event with probability `Pobs = 0.4` in the data, and that in a separate data set simulated under the null hypothesis this probability is different. What I am doing in practice is a little complicated to explain, but in the end I would get a distribution of probabilities. Each of these probabilities is based on resampling of the real data (i.e. bootstrap permutations). I repeat that procedure many times, getting the above mentioned distribution of expected probabilities. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that the vector of expected probabilities is given by:

```r
    set.seed(1234)
    Pexp <- rnorm(n=100, mean = 0.2, sd = 0.05)
```

Intuitively, I would say that the P-value of `Pops` here is the probability of observing a value at least that extreme in the expected distribution. So,

```r
    P <- length(Pexp[Pexp > Pobs]) / length(Pexp)
```

And `P = 0`, which kind of makes sense, but I have a strong feeling I am missing something conceptually important here. Like how should the significance value (e.g. $\alpha = 0.05$) be used here. In this case I also assumed a normal distribution, but my true distribution is likely much more complex, does the principle to getting P value here holds for empirical distributions?

**EDIT**: for clarification, probabilities in this case refer to the probability of a genomic coordinate being sampled at a particular genomic annotation. In the example above, `Pobs = 0.4` might represent a frequency of 40% coordinates that are sampled at "genes", whereas the expectation if the sampling was done taking the observed coordinates and resampling them in the entire genome is lower (`Pexp`).

Comment: Because you use "probability" as if it were some kind of statistic or estimate--which is not what the word means--could you please be more specific about what your "probabilities" might be?  It is strange to use a normal distribution to simulate these quantities because there's an appreciable chance that one or more of your simulated values in `Pexp` will be negative!  For instance, see what happens with a seed of 24 instead of 1234.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Updated the meaning of probabilities for clarity. Hope it makes sense now. Of course, in my real permutations there are on negative probabilities! just wanted to *simplify* things here a little bit.